# Aws sagemaker studio notebook scheduling

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am using sagemaker studio notebook to automate the training process of a model.. I have an IAM role with SageMakerFullAccess and EventBridgeFullAcess policies.. I have created a studio domain with this role.. I am able to schedule the notebook with this role but the job doesn't run at the scheduled time. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Does the job run at all? Are you able to run it on demand through the notebook scheduler tab?

Comment: The job runs when I explicitly give "run job" on the notebook job definition.. Only when it is scheduled it does not run

Comment: Also, it works as expected when i add this in the trust relationship
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
   },
   "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  },
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
   },
   "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
But I assume "AssumeRoles" for lambda and events are not required and I am in a prod env hence its not safe to use this.

Comment: Resurrection, but this vexed me for a day or two. I was scheduling based on my time zone time, not UTC time. I was rushing and not reading everything in the UI while building the job definition. Dumb me.